# Detect uninstallation event in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create a sample WPF application that will perform some task when application is being uninstalled. I could not find any event that can be triggered when application is being uninstalled.

I have tried to use this sample code,

```
public App()
{
    PackageCatalog pk = PackageCatalog.OpenForCurrentPackage();
    pk.PackageUninstalling += PackageUninstalling;
}

private void PackageUninstalling(PackageCatalog sender, PackageUninstallingEventArgs args)
{
    // Do something here
}
```

But this gives System.InvalidOperationException error,

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The process has no package identity. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D54)'

**Edit:** The application is packaged with Windows Application Packaging Project.

**Edit2:** Found the problem, the issue was caused due to unpackaged application. After packaging the issue is gone. Thanks to **mm8**. But I could not find any uninstall event during uninstallation.

Comment: How do you define "uninstallation event"? How do you intend to detect (for example) programs with their own custom installers/uninstallers? Or uninstallers running concurrently under higher-privilege user-accounts? What about MSI? MSIX? AppX? Etc...

Comment: Hi @Dai, thank you for your question. The application will be packaged using Windows Application Packaging Project. I have edited the question.

Comment: Did you run the actual Windows Application Packaging Project and not the application project? An unpackaged app has no package identity.

Comment: Thanks @mm8. After packaging the issue is gone. But I could not get any uninstallation event. I have tried to create a simple beep sound when app is uninstalling but did not get any event.

Comment: See my answer for a possible way to detect the uninstallation.

Answer (score 0):

You must run the actual Windows Application Packaging Project and not the application project. An unpackaged app has no package identity.

To detect the uninstallation, you may be able to use the [desktop6:UninstallAction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-desktop6-uninstallaction?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) package extension which requires the `customInstallActions` restricted capability and specifies an installer file to be run when the user uninstalls the app.

There are no other ways for a closed app to detect this as far as I know.